# hasNextInt won't return false and exit the loop

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to put user input into an array but the hasNextInt() method will not return false and stop the input.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

  int target = in.nextInt();
  while(in.hasNextInt()) {
     weights.insert(in.nextInt());
  }
  recKnapSack(target, 0);
}
```

Comment: Are you closing stdin (e.g. with ctrl-d)? If not, how does it know there's not going to be an int at some point in the future?

Comment: How are you running the code? If you're getting input from the user, then there's *always* a next int.

Comment: *When* would you expect it to return false? Under what condition? I mean, it's very easy to make it return false. Just type *anything* that is not an integer value. Examples: `q`, `x`, `#`, `.`, `Foo`, `Stop now!!!`, `!@#$%^&*`, ...

Comment: what im trying to do is input any amount of int's. Do I have to specify how many int's I want to be input or is there a way to write a loop so that it stops taking input when the user stops entering int's.

Comment: What indicates that the user has stopped entering ints?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.hasNextInt()` will return false when it encounters a non-integer character in its buffer. 
However, it may strip out whitespace when it's reading prompts. So `Space+Enter` or `Enter` will most likely not stop the loop. But any other character will.

Since you'd like to input any number of ints, you must instruct the user on what to type when they're done. In fact, if you're writing a console application, it's a good idea to always explain WHY a program is waiting for input.

Any non-integer will stop the loop condition. In this case the syntax will work as-is, the user just needs some instruction:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the target");
int target = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter weights. Type 'X' to stop");
while(in.hasNextInt()) {
```